# List styling next to floating element

Tags: html, css

Take a look at my example, second list style is totally off because it's next to floating element (unless you add `inline-block` style).

The problem is that I have no way of knowing when the it's next to floating element and it has to work without it like normal (i.e has to be `block`).

How to fix the second list styling?

---

It's rich text editor content, I can't wrap image and second list into div and use flexbox or something else, it has to flow naturally.

**Edit:** even browser is confused - if you press "Run" enough times, bulletins sometimes appear next to text and sometimes above the image on left.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px dashed #ec6161;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

ul {
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Subitem 1</div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>Subitem 2</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div>Item 2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <img src="http://www.pethealthnetwork.com/sites/default/files/content/images/how-introduce-new-cat-home-2-179981446.jpg" />

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Subitem 1</div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>Subitem 2</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div>Item 2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. use `clear:both` to `UL`.

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px dashed #ec6161;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

ul {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  clear:both;
}

img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Subitem 1</div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>Subitem 2</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div>Item 2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <img src="http://www.pethealthnetwork.com/sites/default/files/content/images/how-introduce-new-cat-home-2-179981446.jpg" />

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>Subitem 1</div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div>Subitem 2</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div>Item 2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way of keeping the list next to image and fix the styling without introducing wrapper elements?

Comment: @Solo use display:flex on class .wrapper to inline list and image and also give fixed width to image